# Why do I get white column separators on my custom-drawn listview?

Tags: delphi, listview, colors, brush

Basically, I have the following Delphi 2007 code (CustomDrawItem):

```
procedure TForm1.ListViewCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
 if (Item.SubItems[0] = '...') then
  ListView.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;
end;
```

On my Windows XP, everything works perfectly:

[image: On Windows XP]

But on Windows 7, here's what I have:

[image: On Windows 7]

Now, of course, I'd like to know what's the right code to fill these vertical white stripes. But also, I'd like to know *why* is this happening. Does it come from Delphi? Windows 7? My code?

Comment: I have a faint recollection of this being a known issue, caused by the new operating system.

Comment: BTW, doesn't the world come to an end when you hover the first item on the coloured line?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with Delphi XE2. It is likely just the way ListView controls work on Windows 7. To change the behavior, you will likely have to set `DefaultDraw := False` and then custom-draw the entire background and text for each item as needed.

Comment: I found a simple workaround, but doing any kind of painting in a `CustomDraw` causes a lot of strange rendering bugs, so I'll not even post it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems  a Windows 7 paint behavior, as workaround you can set `ownerdraw` property to true and  use the [`OnDrawItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.OnDrawItem) event instead.

Like so

```
uses
  CommCtrl;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm7.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
 LIndex : integer;
 ListView :  TListView;
 LRect: TRect;
 LText: string;
begin
  ListView:=TListView(Sender);
  for LIndex := 0 to ListView.Columns.Count-1 do
  begin

    if not ListView_GetSubItemRect(ListView.Handle, Item.Index, LIndex, LVIR_BOUNDS, @LRect) then
       Continue;

    if Item.Selected and (not ListView.IsEditing) then
    begin
      ListView.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
      ListView.Canvas.Font.Color  := clHighlightText;
    end
    else
    if (Item.SubItems[0] = '...') then
    begin
      ListView.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;
      ListView.Canvas.Font.Color  := ListView.Font.Color;
    end
    else
    begin
      ListView.Canvas.Brush.Color := ListView.Color;
      ListView.Canvas.Font.Color  := ListView.Font.Color;
    end;

    ListView.Canvas.FillRect(LRect);
    if LIndex = 0 then LText := Item.Caption
    else LText := Item.SubItems[LIndex-1];

    ListView.Canvas.TextRect(LRect, LRect.Left + 2, LRect.Top, LText);
  end;
end;
```

Windows 7

[image]

Windows XP

[image]